# Spring Boot: can we have parts of request mapping as optional using regex?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have an endpoint with multiple request mappings like:

```
@PutMapping(path = {
       "/A/{ACode}/B/{BCode}/C/{CCode}/D/{DCode}",
       "/A/{ACode}/B/{BCode}/D/{DCode}",
       "/A/{ACode}/C/{CCode}/D/{DCode}",
       "/A/{ACode}/D/{DCode}"
})
```

where ACode, BCode, CCode and DCode are all path variables. B, C and their respective codes are optional while A, D and their respective codes are mandatory.

I can call the above API in these ways:

```
PUT /A/IN/B/delhi/C/central/D/110001
PUT /A/IN/B/delhi/D/110001
PUT /A/IN/C/central/D/110001
PUT /A/IN/D/110001
```

I'm trying to combine all of these request mappings into a single regex which can match all of these combinations.

I tried using this regex in mapping but it doesn't work:

```
@PutMapping(path = {
       "A/{ACode:[A-Z]+}(/B/{BCode:[a-z0-9-]+})?(/C/{CCode:[a-z0-9-]+})?/D/{DCode:[a-z0-9-]+}"
})
```

And this one works, but it doesn't make B, C and respective codes optional, so cannot be used:

```
@PutMapping(path = {
       "A/{ACode:[A-Z]+}/B/{BCode:[a-z0-9-]+}/C/{CCode:[a-z0-9-]+}/D/{DCode:[a-z0-9-]+}"
})
```

Is there anything wrong with the regex I used or is there any workaround for achieving this kind of functionality apart from using request params in place of path variables?

Thanks for help!